# How to draw the triangle symbol?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement [the triangle example](http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6972900) yet it fails with d3 v4 for me

```
triangles = [];
triangles.push({x : 250});
triangles.push({x : 350});

var group = svgContainer.append('g').attr('transform','translate('+ xOffset +','+ 30 +')');
var arc = d3.symbol().type('triangle');

var line = group.selectAll('path')
            .data(triangles)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d',arc)
            .attr('fill','red')
            .attr('stroke','#000')
            .attr('stroke-width',1)
            .attr('transform',function(d){ return "translate("+(d.x)+",0)"; });
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: type.apply(...).draw is not a function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of...

```
type("triangle")
```

... it has to be:

```
type(d3.symbolTriangle)
```

Here is [the list](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#symbols) of the symbols in D3 v4.x.

And here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

triangles = [];
triangles.push({
  x: 150
});
triangles.push({
  x: 50
});

var arc = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle);

var line = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(triangles)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', '#000')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + ",30)";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

The same code, rotating the triangles (as you asked in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174396/d3-v4-how-to-plot-triangles/43174450#comment73427154_43174450)):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

triangles = [];
triangles.push({
  x: 150
});
triangles.push({
  x: 50
});

var arc = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle);

var line = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(triangles)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', '#000')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + ",30) rotate(180)";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks, I will try that! How would I do the down pointing triangle? Add a transformation by rotating the symbol?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do it.

Comment: I added that to your example